# Instr for "Line" (skip), "-" (remove "-"), turn postive into negative

Tags: vba, if-statement

Having a bit of an issue with some code here.  I want to do three things.  I want to skip the line in a range if it contains "LINE:", I want to remove any trailing "-" in the string, and I want to turn any positive values into negative values.  Below is my code, but I'm having trouble with it.  I'm getting a "Type mismatch" error on the below line.

```
ElseIf cellh.Value > 0 Then cellh.Value = cellh.Value * 1
```

I'm thinking it's because it's trying to evaluate a range instead of integer, but I need to be able to reference the range to keep the for each going.  Any help would be appreciated.  Code below.  Thanks!

```
Sub Test()

Dim rngh As Range, cellh As Range
Dim myString As String
Set rngh = Range("E1:E24")

For Each cellh In rngh
    If Not InStr(cellh, "LINE:") > 0 Then
    ElseIf InStr(cellh, "-") > 0 Then
        myString = cellh.Text
        myString = Left(myString, Len(myString) - 1)
        cellh.Value = myString
    ElseIf cellh.Value > 0 Then cellh.Value = cellh.Value * -1
    End If
Next cellh

End Sub

LINE: 00005    <--Skip these lines
$12.29-        <--Cut off trailing "-"
$2.59          <--Make a negative number
$13.56-
$2.59 
LINE: 00006
$130.02-
LINE: 00007
$20.13-
$28.74-
LINE: 00008
$41.10-
$13.70-
LINE: 00009
$9.61-
LINE: 00010
$5.00-
$7.18-
LINE: 00011
$7.52-
$8.89-
LINE: 00012
$43.34-
```

Comment: Does any of your cell contains an error?

Comment: Your numbers are text strings that look like numbers?

Comment: Does `If IsError(cellh.Value) Then Stop` break on `Stop`? If so, you have error values in your data; you can't do math or value comparisons on error values. Check with `IsError` *before* you do the math/comparisons.

Comment: Remove the `Not` on `If Not InStr(cellh, "LINE:") > 0 Then` as the line with `LINE:` will return False and move to the ElseIFs

Comment: Your "Type mismatch" is coming from your test of `cellh.Value > 0`.  Cellh is clearly a string and you are trying to compare it like it is an integer.  In order to do the compare, you have to convert your cellh to an integer.  You can do this by creating your own function that verifies you truly have an integer to convert (hint hint... do this).  Or if you are sure it will be an "only numeric text" by the time it gets to the last ElseIf, you can use `cint(cellh.Value) > 0` to convert it.  You'd then need to do the same for `cint(cellh.Value) * -1`

Comment: Thanks guys.  I did end up taking out the 'Not' and the code is running well and doing what it should be.  I think I'm good to go here.  Thanks Scott!  Also, I added in my data just so you can see what I'm trying to work with.